# How make visible a button from another class. Android

Tags: android

New_Game class

> imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
>
> ```
>    public void onClick(View v) {
>        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Image_Quiz.class);>
>
>        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
>        extras.putBoolean("showButton1", true);
>        myIntent.putExtras(extras);
>        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
>        Image_Quiz.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>    }
>
> });
> ```

Image_Quiz class

> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
>    this.setContentView(R.layout.image_quiz);
>    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
>    Boolean showButton = extras.getBoolean("showButton1");
>    if (showButton){
>        this.findViewById(R.Image_Quiz.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>    }
>    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> ```

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

```
   RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

     EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

      TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

      Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buton 1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"

     EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

      Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buton 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        
   RelativeLayout
```

On Image_Quiz class

> ```
>      button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
> ```

Image_Quiz is the class that I switch from this class when I press the imageView1.

When I press the imageView1 it switch on the class Image_Quiz but the button is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a parameter to that activity you are calling, for example:

```
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Image_Quiz.class);
       Bundle extras = new Bundle();
       extras.putBoolean("showButton1", true);
       myIntent.putExtras(extras);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
   }
});
```

and inside your Image_Quiz:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setContentView(R.layout.image_quiz);
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    Boolean showButton = extras.getBoolean("showButton1");
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    if (showButton){
        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        //...you know...
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: not working it says error when I click the image. What should I put on "yourscreen"? I put "id"

Comment: you must put your layout xml name, like crud_person.xml, without the '.xml', so crud_person.